# Is there an API to get a list of gmail filters and update them?

Tags: api, gmail, google-apps

Google Apps has an "[Google Apps Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/)" which allows to [create a new mail filter via an API call](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#creating_a_filter).

Is there any (perhaps undocumented) way to get the list of current filters and update them?

Comment: I am unable to answer it as it is closed but nowadays filter listing is available - see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Filter object was added to the API that allows for filter processing, including retrieval, creation and deletion.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings

Specifically:

**Listing Filters**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/settings/filters
```

Returns a JSON list of *Filter* objects

**Retrieving a specific Filter**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/settings/filters/id
```

Returns a single JSON *Filter* object

**Deleting a specific Filter**

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/settings/filters/id
```

**Creating a Filter**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/settings/filters
```

With a JSON encoded *Filter* in the request body.

While the REST URLs have v1 in the address, they are linked from the current documentation. Also note, GMail API migration is currently in progress, and the deprecated API will cease to function as of **July 2016**. Keep this in mind, as the API may change.

Comment: no api that result in importable list of api ? or api for import ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no API to retrieve filters, only create new ones (as you found).

However, users can export all of their filters from the UI and re-import them into another account manually:

[Using Filters](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579)

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried it, but according to the Google Admin SDK docs, it looks like you can:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#retrieving_labels